# Como carregar DataTable em um DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Tenho um `DataTable` carregado com informações em uma aplicação WPF.

Gostaria de pegar esse `DataTable` e carrega-lo em um `DataGrid`.
Como posso fazer isso da maneira mais fácil ?

`DataGrid` no XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Pedidos&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" Click="Button_Click" Height="27"/>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="268" Width="558"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Creio que quando você atribui ao DataGrid, o seu datatable como DataSource e depois um Bind() nele. Isso faz com que o seu DataTable seja transferido para o seu DataGrid.

Comment: Consegue me enviar um código de exemplo ?

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias maneiras de "popular" um `DataGridView` com um `DataTable`.

Aqui vão duas formas simples de se fazer.

**Usando um `BindingSource`:**

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = seuDataTablePopulado;
datagrid.DataSource = bs;
```

**"Jogando" o `DataTable` direto no grid:**

```
datagrid.DataSource = seuDataTable;
```

Entre essas duas formas eu prefiro usar o `BindingSource` pelas opções de filtros que tenho mais tarde.

Comment: Resolvi de outra forma: `this.meuDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.meuDataTable.DefaultView;`.                          Funcionou da forma que eu queria. Mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda !